# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants' - BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the s in a specific url = https://www.sortlist.fr/pub and select the specific one where the following value is found = "Dupont Lewis". I am using the following code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.sortlist.fr/pub")
BeautifulSoup.find_all("a")
BeautifulSoup("a")
search = BeautifulSoup.select_one("a[title*=Dupont Lewis]")
if len(search)>0:
    print ('I find')
else:
    print ('None')
```

But I get the following error ="AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'"

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You might wanna read the BeautifulSoup documentation first: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you don't create a soup from server response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.sortlist.fr/pub")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')          # <-- create a soup
search = soup.select_one('a[title*="Dupont Lewis"]')    # <-- put "Dupont Lewis" inside ""
if search:                                              # <-- len() isn't necessary, because of .select_one
    print ('I find')
else:
    print ('None')
```

Prints:

```
I find
```